# Need help to apply character limit with condition

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add character limit with three dots(...)
Right now dots are coming on all li tags. It should only come if character limit is greater then 20. I have tried to find the solution on different posts but due to lake of jQuery knowledge I am not able to apply condition. Please assist me on this...

```
<ul>
 <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
 <li>Aliquam porttitor iaculis velit eget elementum</li>
</ul>

$(function() {
  $('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text( $this.text().slice(0, 20) ).append("...");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the length first

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ( $this.text().length > 20 ) {
        $this.text( $this.text().slice(0, 20) + "..." );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/L42f3b9g/)

Note that `$this.text()` returns a string, you concatenate to it, you can't append to it.
You could also use the callback of `text`

```
$('li').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.length > 20 ? txt.slice(20) + '...' : txt;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$this.text($this.text().slice(0, 20) ) + "...")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().length >= 20) {
        $this.text( $this.text().slice(0, 20) ).append("...");
    }
});
```

With this if, you'll filter the li by length.